# G++ compiled application crashes when using std::string or char pointer

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

I just installed MinGW because I wanted to write code using a lightweight code editor instead of Visual Studio or Codeblocks, both of which I never had a problem with. So the code compiles and works, but for some reason it crashes every time I try to use a string or char pointer. For example this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    a = "Hello";
    std::cout << a;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

throws this error when executed:

[image: error]

but this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello";
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Works perfectly:

[image]

(I have tried both with std::string and const char* with no difference)

I have Visual studio 2017 installed, I don't know if that could be the issue.
MinGW version 6.0.3.

PD: I only added C:/MinGW/bin directory to Path environment, don't know if I should add any other directory

Comment: How are you building your program?

Comment: using g++ compiler, simply doing "g++ test.cpp" from cmd, no additional arguments

Comment: "... because I wanted to write code using a lightweight code editor" - Just for your information; you can use whatever editor you please and still use Microsofts `cl.exe` compiler. Nothing *forces* you to use the Visual Studio IDE just to use their compiler. You can even install a version of their toolkit that gives you just the compiler, linker, runtime libraries etc, *without* bundling Visual Studio. The compiler and IDE are *not* tied to eachother.

Comment: It's probably not finding the `.dll` files that comes with your MinGW install. Might need to add the appropriate paths to your Path/Environment Variables.

Comment: Try adding `#include <string>`

Comment: tried with #include <string> before but it makes no difference

Comment: @AgustínMorantes I've used [Win-builds](http://win-builds.org/doku.php) to set up mingw-w64 on my windows machine. I can highly reccomend it if your having issues.

Comment: Don't name your program `test`.

Comment: Why? Anyway i tried renaming it and it does not change the outcome

Comment: Are you trying to code without an IDE? You're not using notepad and the command line are you? Codeblocks is only an IDE, not a compiler, and it actually uses MinGW to compile the code by default. Why would you not want to use something like VS or Codeblocks? It makes life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it! For some reason g++ by default links the std library dynamically. As my program didn't find the dll it was not able to link std::string and std::cout. The solution was to pass the -static-libstdc++ argument to g++.

TL;DR:
Instead of compiling directly like this:

```
g++ somesourcefile.cpp
```

try this argument:

```
g++ somesourcefile.cpp -static-libstdc++
```

Comment: System libraries are always linked dynamically by default